# SoundCloud track search callback not firing

Tags: javascript, callback, jsonp, soundcloud

Code like this (in a script tag) used to work fine in my site some time ago:

"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=" + myId + "&q=" + searchTerm + "&callback=processResultsd&limit=30"

However, now the callback is never fired if the q parameter is included.

If I remove the query term (i.e. "&q=" + searchTerm from the above), the callback is fired fine:

I've tested on JS.do also with the same result, while putting something like http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=myidhidden&q=elephant (for example) directly as URL in a web browser returns a set of search results.

I get the same thing in Safari, Chrome, Firefox.

Can't track search with callback work together like this anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after many experiments and much searching, it seems that this will work:

"http://api.soundcloud.com/search?client_id=" + myId + "&q=" + searchTerm + "&callback=processResultsd&limit=30"

with:
function processResults(returnData) {};

The callback function then has to use returnData.collection to access the array of results, rather than returnData itself being the array which it is with the /tracks? result.

Whether this is the correct way to do this is I don't know, but the callback is now fired. Perhaps this will help others also...